# Pass parameters to html from MongoDB API in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, electron

So, I am building an electron app for personal usage and I am using MongoDB Atlas for the backend with my Node app. I am new with Electron, so trying things out still, so might be a silly mistake.

preload.js

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

process.once("loaded", () => {
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('versions', process.version);
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('engineAPI', {
        userLogin: (...args) => ipcRenderer.invoke('engine:userLogin', ...args).then(result => { console.log(result); return result }),
    });
});
```

electron.js

```js
// DEPENDENCIES
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// MONGOOSE ADAPATER CALL
const mongooseAdapter = require('../engine/common/mongoose.adapter');

// CONTROLLER CALLS
const userController = require('../engine/controllers/user.controller');

// Create the native Window function to be called within Electron initiation
function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1366,
        height: 768,
        // Set the path of an additional "preload" script that can be used to
        // communicate between node-land and browser-land.
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
        },
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./src/pages/index.html"));
    if (!app.isPackaged) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished its initialization and
// is ready to create the browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    try {
        ipcMain.handle('engine:userLogin', userController.userLogin);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    mongooseAdapter.connect(1).then(() => {
        createWindow();
        console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Not connected. Exiting now...', err);
        process.exit();
    });

    app.on('activate', () => {
        // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
        // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS.
// There, it's common for applications and their menu bar to stay active until
// the user quits  explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

// If your app has no need to navigate or only needs to navigate to known pages,
// it is a good idea to limit navigation outright to that known scope,
// disallowing any other kinds of navigation.
const allowedNavigationDestinations = "https://my-electron-app.com";
app.on("web-contents-created", (event, contents) => {
    contents.on("will-navigate", (event, navigationUrl) => {
        const parsedUrl = new URL(navigationUrl);
        if (!allowedNavigationDestinations.includes(parsedUrl.origin)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

index.html

```html
<form id="loginForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(event)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" id="showPassword" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="togglePasswordVisibility()">Show</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

partial js file mapped to the index.html (app.js)

```
// Function to handle form submission
async function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hi");
    //Fetching input fields for login creds
    var data = {
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value
    };

    const response = await window.engineAPI.userLogin(data);
    console.log(response);
}
```

Node.js & Mongoose API

```js
const userModel = require('../models/user.model');

exports.userLogin = async (event, args) => {
    try {
        userModel.findOne({ email: args.email }).then(userData => {
            console.log(userData);
            return userData
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    };
};
```

This API returns the correct values in the log when called within the Node.js API. However, when I am trying to read the same values in the app.js file from where the API got called, it is coming as undefined.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:
Added the mongoose adapter code below:**

```js
// CONFIG CALL
const config = require('../../private/config');

// DEPENDENCIES
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {
    connect: function (flag) {
        switch (flag) {
            case 1:
                return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    try {
                        const connection = await mongoose.connect(config.dbUrl).catch(error => reject(error));
                        resolve(connection);
                    } catch (error) {
                        reject(error)
                    }
                })
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, rather stupid when you think about it.

The issue was with Node's async behaviour. I added an await structure in the Node.js API and removed the promise. and it worked.

Updated code below for anyone's reference:

Node.js API

```
const userModel = require('../models/user.model');
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

exports.userLogin = async (event, args) => {
    try {
        const userData = await userModel.findOne({ email: args.email }).catch(error => console.log(error));
        return userData
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    };
};
```

preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

process.once("loaded", () => {
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('versions', process.version);
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('engineAPI', {
        userLogin: (...args) => ipcRenderer.invoke('engine:userLogin', ...args),
    });
});
```